# The list of restricted second-level domains such as .co.uk and .ac.jp

Tags: data-request, metadata, web-crawling

Some country-code top-level domains (ccTLD) contain general-purpose second-level domains, like `.co` and `.ac`, so the end user of the domain is identified with the third-level domain, such as `oxford.ac.uk`.

Where can I get the full list of such domains?

Answer (score 3):

This "restricted domain" is known an effective top-level domain (eTLD)", or a  suffix. By Mozilla:

> "A "public suffix" is one under which Internet users can (or historically could) directly register names. Some examples of public suffixes are .com, .co.uk and pvt.k12.ma.us. The Public Suffix List is a list of all known public suffixes.

### Public Suffix List by Mozilla

- https://publicsuffix.org/

> The Public Suffix List is an initiative of Mozilla, but is maintained as a community resource. It is available for use in any software, but was originally created to meet the needs of browser manufacturers. It allows browsers to, for example:
>
> Avoid privacy-damaging "supercookies" being set for high-level domain name suffixes
>
> Highlight the most important part of a domain name in the user interface
>
> Accurately sort history entries by site

### public-suffix-metalist

- https://github.com/QA2/public-suffix-metalist

> This repository is an attempt to document the many places where hardcoded domain suffix information lives. Databases, registries, software source code, etc. Some of these registries are publically available, while other registries may be part of closed-source programs or live in a config file maintained by a SaaS provider. All of these registries are considered in-scope for this registry.